# Is there a way I can specify a different repository for the CocoaPods master repo?

Tags: cocoapods

At my work, we have a private cocoapods repository that we use to host whitelisted libraries for developers, and I am trying to validate a library I wrote.

Whenever i do a `pod spec lint MYPODNAME --verbose`, CocoaPods tries to validate my spec against the `master` repo instead of my private repo.

Is there any way to get around this behavior?

I have tried completely removing the master repo, but it still attempts to validate my pod's dependencies against `master`

EDIT: [This issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2543) seems to describe what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. You have to manually specify the `--sources` for what CocoaPods will validate the spec against.

`pod spec lint MYPODNAME --verbose --sources=git@<DOMAIN>:<REPO>.git`